# Formalisation of equivalence of "vectors" and "points"

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In all the linear algebra courses I've taken, the notion of a "geometric vector" has not been rigorously defined. All that has been explained is that we can think of them as algebraically equivalent to points, but geometrically they can be "moved" around without changing. How do you define these things formally? Below is my attempt; is it adequate, and are there better definitions out there?

A geometric vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^{2N}/\text{~}$, where ~ is defined as follows: Writing a general element of $\mathbb{R}^{2N}$ as (tail, tip) or $(\bf{a}, \bf{b})$ for $\bf{a}, \bf{b}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^N$, we have
$$(\bf{a}, \bf{b}) \; \text{~} \; (\bf{c}, \bf{d}) \leftrightarrow \bf{d} - \bf{b} = \bf{c} - \bf{a}.$$
The vector space isomorphism between this quotient (endowed with fairly obvious operations) and $\mathbb{R}^N$ is not hard to show. Also, (tail$_1$, tip$_1$) ~ (tail$_2$, tip$_2$) exactly when you can "move" the corresponding vectors to each other, so ~ captures the concept of "moving".

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Informally: vectors live in vector spaces, points live in affine spaces. In particular, you can't add points.

Comment: I'm familiar with "vectors" as they occur in the description of general vector spaces. I'm really interested in how you can define what a "geometric vector" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the notion of affine space (as opposed to vector space).

A vector space is a set $E$ together with an additive law $+$ and scalar multiplication (satisfying the usual axioms). Naturally $\mathbb{R}^n$ is endowed with a vector space structure.

An affine space $A$ directed by a vector space $E$ is a set $A$ together with a "faithful and transitive group action of $E$", i.e. a group morphism 
$t : E \rightarrow B(A)$ (where $B(A)$ is the set of bijections of $A$) such that :

- for all $a,b \in A$, there is a $x \in E$ with $t(x)a=b$  (transitive)
- for all $x \in E$, if $x \neq 0$ then $t(x)$ is not the identity map (faithful)

What this formal definition represents is $t(x)$ is the translation of vector $x$. The elements of $A$ are points, which are moved by vectors through the action of $t$. Note that if $E$ is a vector space then it has a natural affine structure. This is the most formal definition of affine spaces/vector spaces, which has at least the advantage of clearly separating the different concepts (points and vectors). Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up nicely. It's quite intuitive to think of vectors "directing" points, but not something I'd considered before.

Answer (score 0):

In each mathematical system you will find basic concepts that won't/can't be defined, their interrelationships are as described by the relevant axioms. Think "elements" and "operations" in a group. Yes, you can give examples ("look, the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ with $+$ form a group") or give some other analogy to give a mental picture ("a vector can be considered a point in space, and ..."), but what you really have to understand is the abstract aspect.

[Somebody said about mathematics that "abstract algebra is the subject that separates adults from children"; meaning that this subject is *hard*, and a thorough understanding is the basis for further advances.]

Comment: That's a fair point, and something I did consider. I guess my problem was that I felt it isn't right to assert equivalence between two objects, only one of which you have defined. There seems to be a gap there. (For the record, you can define a group operation properly -- it's a certain kind of function -- but the point about elements stands.)

Comment: I have to disagree with vonbrand. Maybe the notion of elements is not well defined in mathematics, but the notion of operation is (it is a certain map from $E \times E$ to $E$ satisfying certain properties), the notion of map is itself defined (it is a certain subset of $E \times F$) and the notions of affine spaces and vector spaces most definitely are precisely defined !

Comment: @JoshuaCiappara, you can "assert" equivalence as an analogy. And yes, I'm aware of the rigurous _description_ of the group operation as a function, but that doesn't tell you what it _is_ (and it can be wildly different things, depending on the exact group you have in hand). Part of the point of "abstract", really: If you don't pin it down, it can be used in lots of different situations.